# create.js being flagged as malicious by ad networks

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, create.js

I have created some html5 banners using Animate for ad networks like DCM, Amazon, etc. and they are now telling me they cannot use the files due to the fact that the files are calling for the external js file (see below is what Amazon is telling me is not acceptable). How can i resolve this? Any help would be much appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWU4c.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the [amazon advertising Technical guidelines](https://advertising.amazon.com/ad-specs/en/policy/technical-guidelines):

> All content must only come from the serving ad server’s domain and the content served may not call in content from any other domain.

[DoubleClick hosts commonly used libraries which you can include.](https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/6307288?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you. Yes that much I understand. So is it as simple as pulling that create.js code and having it reside as a seperate js file in the same directory as the ad files?

Comment: @pete Yeah. Download the file which you are currently linking from another domain and put it on your local server. Then link to it directly.

Comment: Thanks again. My only concern is running into file size problems when including these libraries with my ads. It seems DCM at least has created locally hosted versions of create.js to account for this (see link). I'm trying to find out how best to solve for this for other ad networks.
https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/6307288?hl=en

Comment: Amazon for example allows the use of the DCM library. See [here](https://advertising.amazon.com/ad-specs/en/policy/technical-guidelines#third-party-html-desktop-advertising-guidelines-) under HTML Ad security.